# How to come out of loop while reading input in c++?

Tags: c++, string, cin

I am having a code snippet as shown:

```
void func() {
    string text;
    while( std::getline(cin,text)) {
            words[i++] = text;
        }
}
```

While entering input, i am not able to come out of the loop once i finish entering. 
Printing 'Enter' key doesn't help.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Press the "end of file" key sequence. Which is different depending on operating system.

Comment: Or see if the string is empty inside the loop, and then `break` out of it.

Comment: I'm not sure, but as I remember, in windows end of file can be create with pressing `CTRL+Z`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes that check works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replaced the check as :

```
while( std::getline(cin,text) && text.length())
```

And now it worked successfully on pressing the enter without text.

Comment: Try ctrl + z it is more simply.

Comment: You may be able to enter ctrl + d on some platforms.